# XSLT: XML element attributes appearing outside of element

Tags: xml, xslt

So I'm new to XSLT and honestly find them extremely confusing.  The current input XML is styled as follows:

```
<chapter prev_label="5">
    <title>Chapter Title</title>
    <section prev_label="5.1">
        <title>Section 5.1 Title
            <indexterm>
                <primary>index1a</primary>
                <secondary>index1b</secondary>
            </indexterm>
        </title>
        <para>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel hendrerit urna. Pellentesque non ante ac felis ullamcorper scelerisque ut vitae tellus. Cras a auctor nulla, a faucibus leo. Fusce iaculis purus         tempor. quis tincidunt mattis. Nunc elit ex, ultrices quis tincidunt vitae, efficitur eu quam. Curabitur mollis egestas
        </para>
        <subsection prev_label="5.1.1">
            <title>Subsection 5.1.1 Title
                <indexterm>
                    <primary>index2a</primary>
                    <secondary>index2b</secondary>
                </indexterm>
            </title>
            <seqlist>
                <item prev_label="1.">ucibus ullamcorper sit amet neclibero.</item>
                <item prev_label="2.">Fusce a tortor bibendum, iaculis mi vitae.</item>
            </seqlist>
        </subsection>
    </section>
</chapter>
```

My desired output would look like:

```
<section prev_label="5.1">
    <title>Section 5.1 Title
    </title>
    <para>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel hendrerit urna. Pellentesque non ante
        ac felis ullamcorper scelerisque ut vitae tellus. Cras a auctor nulla, a faucibus leo. Fusce iaculis purus
        tempor. quis tincidunt mattis. Nunc elit ex, ultrices quis tincidunt vitae, efficitur eu quam. Curabitur mollis egestas
    </para>
    <subsection prev_label="5.1.1">
        <title>Subsection 5.1.1 Title
        </title>
        <seqlist>
            <item prev_label="1.">ucibus ullamcorper sit amet nec libero.</item>
            <item prev_label="2.">Fusce a tortor bibendum, iaculis mi vitae.</item>
        </seqlist>
    </subsection>
</section>
```

Any section/subsection can have seqlist tags, para tags or both.  I want those to remain in my resulting output, while removing all indexterm tags and their children.  The other issue I'm having is based on the app I'm running the user will select either just section, or section and subsection.  In all cases all "children" subsections should be shown in the output.  So if section 5.1 is selected, section 5.1 and all subsections starting with 5.1 should be displayed.  if subsection 5.1.1 is selected all subsections starting with 5.1.1 will be displayed.  The lowest scope of subsections is 4 digits, (i.e. 5.1.1.4).  I hope that makes sense.  Because the way our REST calls are formatted to the back end that has the initial XML work, we have two .xsl files, one for section and one for subsection. If the user selects a section, the section XSL is applied, if the user selects a subsection, the subsection XSL is applied. (i.e. www.restserver.com/book/5/5.1 would select a section and www.restserver.com/book/5/5.1/5.1.2 would select the subsection)

section XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="sectionId"/>
<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <sectionBody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section"/>
    </sectionBody>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="section[@prev_label=$sectionId]"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="section[@prev_label=$sectionId]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::indexterm)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

subsection XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="subsectionId"/>
<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <subsectionBody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section"/>
    </subsectionBody>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="subsection"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="subsection">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="subsection[@prev_label=$subsectionId]"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="subsection[starts-with(@prev_label,$subsectionId)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::indexterm)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem I'm having is that for some reason (which I'm sure is obvious some someone more XSL savvy than I am) the prev_label attributes on section and subsection is being...pulled out? my output currently looks like this:

```
<sectionBody>
    <section>5.1
        <title>Section 5.1 Title
        </title>
        <para>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel hendrerit urna. Pellentesque non ante
        ac felis ullamcorper scelerisque ut vitae tellus. Cras a auctor nulla, a faucibus leo. Fusce iaculis purus
        tempor. quis tincidunt mattis. Nunc elit ex, ultrices quis tincidunt vitae, efficitur eu quam. Curabitur
        mollis egestas
        </para>
        <subsection>5.1.1
            <title>Subsection 5.1.1 Title
            </title>
            <seqlist>
            <item prev_label="1.">ucibus ullamcorper sit amet nec libero.</item>
            <item prev_label="2.">Fusce a tortor bibendum, iaculis mi vitae.</item>
            </seqlist>
        </subsection>
    </section>
</sectionBody>
```

Everything I have tried either doesn't have the prev_label attribute in the right place, or brings back the unwanted  tags.  I have a feeling the two xsl files are stomping on each other, but I can't quite single out the problem.  I'm not sure if it's relevant, but if the user only selects a section, the subsection tags will be output correctly, however the section prev_label tag will appear outside of the tag as seen in the incorrect output.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship of the two stylesheets. Is one applied to the result of the other?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't made clear.  I clarified the original post, but basically a REST call is sent to one of our backend servers to retrieve the XML to be used.  If the user selects only a section (i.e. www.restserver.com/book/5/5.1) the section.xsl is used, if the user selects a subsection (i.e. www.restserver.com/book/5/5.1/5.1.2) the subsection.xsl is used.

Comment: you are using `copy-of` in your last template, the attribute you are applying in `subsection` has nowhere to go. change the last template into an identity template and see.